# Choose and connect a camera to a robot

Tags: cameras

There are tons of cameras in devices around us these days. There are used photo cameras, smartphones, tablets at my home gathering dust.

I wonder, what the easiest way could be to get a camera module from some device, connect it to my robot project with a soldering iron and make it work from the software point of view. I am planning to use something like Arduino, an STM32 platform, or probably Intel Edison.

May be some camera modules are easier to solder and program for a custom  project? Or shouldn't I look this way and better find a camera module that is specially designed for custom projects?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't chosen a camera module yet.  It also sounds like you haven't chosen a hardware platform yet.  Which pair of camera and processor to use is a fairly subjective choice, based on the information you provided.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it's too broad. You have "cameras", and you want to connect them to "microcontrollers" to make a "robot project". Without anything specific, nobody can give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Sergei Basharov, but I'm afraid that questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. Also, the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) has good advice on how to write a good question. If you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to pour water on your fire... while it is certainly possible, whether it is worth the effort is debatable.

While different tablets/smartphones/cameras will employ different optical devices, they will be more or less the same.

This question has been asked before on SE Arduino, [Re-use smartphone/tablets parts like a camera](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19019/re-use-smartphone-tablets-parts-like-a-camera). [jwpat7's answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19019/re-use-smartphone-tablets-parts-like-a-camera#answer-19026) goes into specifics for a particular Samsung tablet. You don't specify which tablet/phones you have, so I can not provide any further detailed information, but open up the device and see if it has `HRS` on the connector.

Note that [cortices' answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19019/re-use-smartphone-tablets-parts-like-a-camera#answer-19107) advises against doing so, due to propriety signals, and the difficulty in decoding them.

A link to the Arduino forum is also provided, [How to reuse quality camera from old / broken phone](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=269272.0), which, more or less, also recommends against the idea due to the effort required in [reverse engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=camera).

It would probably be far simpler to use a Raspberry Pi, which has an actual camera interface (CSI port) for use with the [camera module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/camera-module-setup/). You can then use the Python package, [picamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unused smartphone with a camera, your best bet may be to simply use that for the robot.

Many results came up in my brief google search for smartphone robots and smartphone-based robotics software.